# lineStyle removed after colorTransform

Tags: actionscript-3, flashdevelop

I have these shapes with a lineStyle to outline the shapes, however, when I tried to do colorTransform, it will completely remove the outline of the shapes. Is there a way to make lineStyle constant? To permanently stay after the colorTransform? I don't quite understand as I thought colorTransform is just changing the color of the shape.

```
            char.graphics.lineStyle(0, 0x000000);
            char.graphics.beginFill(0xFFFFFF, 1);
            char.graphics.drawEllipse(x, y, 25, 25);
            char.graphics.endFill();
```

I have the outline as black and inside is all white.

```
            changeColor = char.transform.colorTransform;
            changeColor.color = 0xFFFFFF;
            char.transform.colorTransform = changeColor;
```

Once I change the shapes back to white to their original color, the lineStyle disappears. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score -1):

take a look at this page

https://stackoverflow.com/a/796731/5862335

as there is explained you have to put your strokes in another DisplayObject.